# Restore cookies in onResume() Android app?

Tags: android, cookies

I'm trying to maintain a user session in my android app. My login works like this: I make a **request to an API** and send the user email and password, if the user actually exists then I get a JSONObject and manage it using GSON. That works just fine. I also **get the cookies** into a **CoookieStore** and save them into the **SharedPreferences**

Thing is, every time the app is paused I apparently lost the cookies and I am not able to make any other requests to the API because, of course, I'm not authorised.

**Is there any way I can restore the cookies from SharedPreferences in the onResume() method?**

I tried so, like this:

**InteractionManager** is the class where I manage everything that has to do with making requests and getting responses from the API

so in my activity I did this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
    super.onResume();

    //Create a new instance of cookieStore to set it 
    //into the InteractionManager CookieStore when 
    //the app gets resumed.

    CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();

    String name = "user_credentials";
    String value = prefs.getString(name, "");

    Cookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie(name, value);
    cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);

    name = "user_class";
    value = prefs.getString(name, "");
    Log.d(TAG, "user_class cookie: " + value);
    cookie = new BasicClientCookie(name, value);

    interactionManager.setCookieStore(cookieStore);
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
    interactionManager.setLocalContext(localContext);

}
```

but apparently I'm not doing it right, because the API keeps saying I am not authorised which is probably because I'm doing something wrong managing the cookies.

What am I doing wrong?

Hope anyone can help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can use [android-async-http](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) which is very powerful an flexible http client for android.

Base on its documentaion you can easily make use of cookies in your android application:

First, create an instance of AsyncHttpClient:

```
AsyncHttpClient myClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
```

Now set this client’s cookie store to be a new instance of PersistentCookieStore, constructed with an activity or application context (usually this will suffice):

```
PersistentCookieStore myCookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(this);
myClient.setCookieStore(myCookieStore);
```

Any cookies received from servers will now be stored in the persistent cookie store.

To add your own cookies to the store, simply construct a new cookie and call addCookie:

```
BasicClientCookie newCookie = new BasicClientCookie("cookiesare", "awesome");
newCookie.setVersion(1);
newCookie.setDomain("mydomain.com");
newCookie.setPath("/");
myCookieStore.addCookie(newCookie);
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Am I supposed to have one instance of AsyncHttpClient for each one of my requests? I have to do several requests in several activities. Do I have to create on new client everytime?

Comment: You could have multiple async-http-clients, but best practice is to provide one instance either by creating it in Application class or by a singleton class.

Comment: Got it. Do you know any good tutorials of AsyncHttpClient? I really have no idea how to start because I literally have to change ALL my application to use the library.

Comment: [its documentation](http://loopj.com/android-async-http) is pretty straightforward. You simply create a http-client. then call `get` or 'post` or 'put` method of the http-client and pass the method a response callback.

Comment: Ok, thanks. One more question, will an instance of PersistentCookieStore still have its data even if the activity gets paused?

Comment: I'm not quiet sure, but as far as I remember, you should put them both into one `context`, for example in onCreate() of a Custom `Application` class, put these code:     asyncHttpClient.getHttpClient().
                getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.ALLOW_CIRCULAR_REDIRECTS, true);
        PersistentCookieStore persistentCookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(this);
        asyncHttpClient.setCookieStore(persistentCookieStore);

Comment: You should also provide a public static reference to that http-client, something like this:     public static AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();

Comment: Thanks to those who create this awesome library!